# is there a way to use an ajax call on a view in MVC to refresh your page with new information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I know this doesn't really go comfort the guidelines of MVC. But in this case it seems rather dumb to go over an entire Controller method rather than updating the view in the view. Basically i want something to be shown only when the checkbox is checked and it dissappears again after it's no longer checked. I was thinking maybe make a boolean and adjust this within the view with an if statement. This would mean that the entire page would have to reload and show only the data based on the checked or unchecked checkbox. Is there a way to do this or should i just stick to the MVC model, make a partial view and reload the information based on that or another suggestion? i already have the model loaded so the information isn't really needed anywhere as it's only how the view shows it.

Comment: there are many ways have you researched little on SO?

Comment: i'm rather new to it all so my best answer would be no but maybe i'm just not using the correct searching terms. i did however do a ajax call to my controller and my controller returned data.. so that's kind of the only way i know how

Comment: you need to write jquery event for checkbox and in that event send ajax call to controler's action and load partial view on page

Comment: yes it is possible ,I think the best thing is go for mvc sample projects,download it and study that, i think lot of examples already in net for solving this problem

Comment: Ajax is used to communicate with the server. It doesn't sound like you need to do that. For what you describe you only need very, very basic JS + DOM.

Comment: .... i know how to send it to the controller but i don't want that it's kind of a long way around when i could just reload the page and check the value of the checkbox...

Comment: ok i got it figured out how to reload the page.. now is there a way to get the checkbox value runtime?

Comment: yes you can get via jquery

Comment: i actually meant in my razor view with an @if()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a partial view to store the content that is dependent on the checkbox.

On the checkbox click you can do an ajax call to load that partial view, if you have really any data that gets updated in that area.

If you just need to hide/show based on the checkbox click, just use jquery to hide or show that div.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox">
<div id="ShowHideArea">
    <p>some content</p>
</div>
 <script>
$(function() {
$('#myCheckbox').change(function() {
   $('#ShowHideArea').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
 });
```

});

Comment: that's actually not how i meant it...... ok i got it figured out how to reload the page.. now is there a way to get the checkbox value runtime?

Comment: $("input[type='checkbox']").val();
If you have multiple checkboxes: $('#checkbox_id').val();

Comment: i actually meant in my razor view with an @if()

Comment: Does your model contains the checkbox value?

Comment: no it's a seperate checkbox value it's meant for a profile to check wether or not the person seeing the view wants to see personal information of the person

Comment: If it is not part of the model then you can't use @if to get the checkbox value at runtime. You need to use jquery. Anyhow you are doing ajax call to get the data from controller, right? there you can use the above jquery to get the checkbox value.

Comment: no i was hoping to avoid using the controller.. but i geuss that's not possible then

Comment: The area that you want to reload, does that have data also which gets updated?

Comment: Then no need to load or reload the page. Simply use the below javascript to achieve the same:


<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox">
<div id="ShowHideArea">
    <p>some content</p>
</div>
You can use javascript on a razorview also, adding a section: <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
    $('#myCheckbox').change(function() {
        $('#ShowHideArea').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
     });
    });
</script>

Comment: owh right thanks sorry i didn't quite understand from first part ;)